# Is the spread / rest operator necessary for typescript array declarations?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Reading through some code that looks like this:

```
export function printAdd(...numbers: number[]) {
    alert(`Adding the numbers: ${numbers.join(', ')}`);
}
```

Is the `...` in `...numbers` necessary.  IIUC that means that numbers is an array, but we are also declaring that with `number[]`, so it seems we are double dipping?

Comment: The `...` means you call `printAdd(1, 2, 3)`. Without it, you'd call it like `printAdd([1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: OK so essentially it destructures the passed in array into arguments?  IIUC printAdd([1,2,3]) would work the same way?

Comment: It is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Other way around. It takes the `arguments` and makes a proper array out of them. [You can look at the generated JavaScript to see the emitted code if you want to know exactly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20printAdd(...numbers%3A%20number%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(%60Adding%20the%20numbers%3A%20%24%7Bnumbers.join('%2C%20')%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%7D). I mean, the compiler will also catch any calls you've made where you've called it with strings or other types of course.

Comment: OK Got it - Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the ... in ...numbers necessary?

No, but the answer to this question depends entirely on your intended use of the parameters.

In the example you cited, the `...` indicates a [rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters). Using this will group all arguments specified when invoking the function in an array of the specified type (in this case the type is `number`). Consider the following example function and invocations:

```
export function printAdd(...numbers: number[]) {
    alert(`Adding the numbers: ${numbers.join(', ')}`);
}

printAdd(1, 2, 3);    // Valid because there are 0 or more arguments of type number
printAdd([1, 2, 3]);  // Not valid because there is a single argument and it is of type number[]
```

Not using a rest parameter indicates to the compiler that the function expects to receive a single argument of type `number[]`.

```
export function printAdd(numbers: number[]) {
    alert(`Adding the numbers: ${numbers.join(', ')}`);
}

printAdd(1, 2, 3);    // Not valid because there are 3 arguments of type number
printAdd([1, 2, 3]);  // Valid because there is a single argument of type number[]
```

This is made more obvious by analyzing the output of the Typescript compiler. When compiled, the first example becomes:

```
// COMPILER OUTPUT
function printAdd() {
    var numbers = [];
    for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        numbers[_i] = arguments[_i];
    }
    alert("Adding the numbers: " + numbers.join(', '));
}
```

Note the use of the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object. This is an array-like object but it is not an array. Meaning you can't use any of the `Array.prototype` methods on it.

The second example becomes

```
// COMPILER OUTPUT
function printAdd(numbers) {
    alert("Adding the numbers: " + numbers.join(', '));
}
```

The `arguments` object is not used and `numbers` is an `Array`, so `Array.prototype` methods are immediately available for use.